# Cloud function callable await firestore transaction

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im building a react native app with a Firebase backend, I try to use cloud functions but I cant make them work :
My function :

```
exports.funcName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>{
    let pseudo = data.pseudo
    let querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("saved").where("pseudoCreateur", "==", pseudo).get()
    return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
})
```

And I'm calling with this :

```
const func = functions().httpsCallable('funcName');

func({
    pseudo: 'abc'
}).then(res => {
    console.log('success')
    console.log(res)
})
```

But I'm getting Error: INTERNAL without no more details. I think the problem is due to the await but I dont know how I can deal with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the logs in the Cloud Functions console.  It should give you more information.

You're trying to use `await` without a matching `async` keyword.  `await` can only be used in a function that was declared `async`.  The callback function that you pass to onCall should be declared `async` if you want to use `await` in it.

```
exports.funcName = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) =>{
    let pseudo = data.pseudo
    let querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("saved").where("pseudoCreateur", "==", pseudo).get()
    return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
})
```